# How to create IAP tunnel for windows VM with no external ip

Tags: google-cloud-platform, window, rdp

How can I setup IAP tunnel to GCP windows vm with no external ip in order to rdp from outside gcp when required

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I was particularly for this document " https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding "

Answer (score 2):

Cloud IAP uses TCP forwarding to provide access via SSH or RDP to VM instances without Public IP and bastion host.

Here are quick start guides you may follow:

[Protecting your cloud VMs with Cloud IAP context-aware access controls](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/protecting-your-cloud-vms-with-cloud-iap-context-aware-access-controls)

[Cloud IAP enables context-aware access to VMs via SSH and RDP without bastion hosts](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/cloud-iap-enables-context-aware-access-to-vms-via-ssh-and-rdp-without-bastion-hosts)